# Subject repetition with a pronoun

Tags: pronoms, sujet, pronoms-personnels, emphase

From the newspaper:

> Une proposition de loi – retoquée en 2012 par le Sénat – Cispa a **elle** été adoptée par la Chambre des représentants en avril.

Can I remove *elle* from the sentence? If so, what's the effect on the overall meaning? In sentences like this, is it more common to repeat the subject in the form of a personal pronoun or is it just personal taste?

Comment: *La Cispa a, elle, été adoptée par la Chambre des représentants en avril*. The "," (or "-") is mandatory because it replaces *La Cispa a, quant à elle, été adoptée par la Chambre des représentants en avril*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not mandatory, it's a way to put emphasis on the subject, most probably because there was previous mention of a rejected law proposal.  It's always a pronoun which is used for the repetition and it is the emphasized form (*moi*, *toi*, *lui*, *eux* instead of *je*, *tu*, *il*, *ils*). Personally, I'd have put the *elle* between comas:

> La proposition de loi Cispa a, elle, été adoptée par la Chambre.

Note that it's something different than the repetition of the subject, common, sometimes mandatory, in questions. There, one expect the subject to be after the verb but in some cases, for instance when the subject is too complex, the subject is before the verb and a [pronom-de-reprise](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronom-de-reprise) repeat it after.

Comment: I would say the purpose of the pronoun is to express a contrast rather than just emphasis.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, in this case the emphasis is to mark the opposition, but I'm not sure it is the only case where that structure is used even if all the examples I can think of now are using _moi-même_ and so on instead of just _moi_.